# Generate unique Alphanumeric identifiers in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am creating a tracking app for projects where each project will have one or more groups. I want to add an alphanumeric string as the unique identifier (similar to the primary key) for groups. I know about UUID but it is a long string and I am looking for 10-15 characters long.

Could you please help me with how can I generate a unique string?

I want field "project_groupid" as a unique identifier.

Models.py

```
class project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=130,default="")
    project_customer = models.ForeignKey(customerOrganization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class project_target(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_groupid = models.CharField(max_length=20,default="")
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    group_country = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="US")
    group_language = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="en")
```

Comment: "random.choice" doesn't guaranty for the uniqueness. Not sure if UUID4 will have unique numbers over the time.

Comment: I assume the OP has means of checking whether the newly generated random string hasn't been used previously (and repeating the process until a unique one is generated).

Comment: That's the way but wanted to see if we can generate unique ids without checking the database.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Could you please provide some sample code. This helps give context for others to answer your question. Often we see request for solutions whereas that might not be the right way to tackle your problem

Comment: Sure, Code has been updated. I have added models.py where "project_groupid" should be alphanumeric unique identifier for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Django have a helper function for generating random strings `get_random_string`, it's usage is simple, pass the length and list of charters to use

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
get_random_string(10, 'abcdef0123456789')
```

However this method do not grant unique values, over time you may get the same random string, you should check against your database if the generated random identifier already exists

Comment: Is there any way if I need to generate 50000 unique ids in a single shot.

Comment: Use loops to do that